# Editable Custom Field in Folder View in Outlook Desktop

Tags: outlook

I am wanting a custom filed added next to the subject field in a folder view.
I am wanting to be able to type some text in the field for each email in the folder.
I have experience with excel VBA , but not outlook
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean in the message list? Or in the reading pane?

Comment: In the Message List idealy, however i will settle for the reading pane if i have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cannot do it in the message list view, but you can create a task pane to be shown next to the reading pane - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Comment: It's a bit beyond my current VBA Skills, however from the link provided I believe it will solve my problem. Thank you